# iphone camera uploading

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

in xcode 4.3 Im trying to take a picture using the camera from in the app and use that image or one from the picture library to add here------->

```
(void) ShareButton {
[AddThisSDK showAddThisButtonInView:self.view
                          withFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 150, 50)
                             forImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"**HERE**"]
                          withTitle:@"Share Your Dinner"
                        description:@""];
}
```

My camera is fully working i just don't know how to get the image name there if you need any more info or a better explanation feel free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 forImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"**HERE**"]
```

You should be using this:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *myImageFromCamera = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [AddThisSDK showAddThisButtonInView:self.view
                          withFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 150, 50)
                             forImage:myImageFromCamera
                          withTitle:@"Share Your Dinner"
                        description:@""];
}
```

`UIImagePickerController`'s didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate method can be used to detect when the user has pressed the "Use" button in the picker. As shown above, it then creates a `UIImage` for what ever image was taken by the user, then we set this image as the `AddThisSDK` sharing image.

Mind you, this is an over simplification and won't actually directly perform what you want. In order for this to be done properly you will want to declare your `UIImage` globally so that you can set the image in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo and then call for it later in your AddThisSDK sharing method.

**Note:** `forImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"**HERE**"]` tells the method that it should be using an image named "**HERE**" that is saved in your applications bundle.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *myImageFromCamera = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [AddThisSDK showAddThisButtonInView:self.view
                              withFrame:CGRectMake(75, 50, 150, 50)
                               forImage:myImageFromCamera
                              withTitle:@"Share Your Dinner"
                            description:@""];

    NSString *mediaType = [info
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [info
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        imageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
}
```

This worked perfectly, the photo that you take or choose from the roll show up with the share button

Comment: If my post helped you then please mark it as the correct answer.